# How to classify dates as last 3 months, or last 6 months and so on from in a table using calculated column in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

[image: Input]

I want to have an additional column that basically classifies the `Date` column as the `last 3 months`, `last 6 months`, `last 9 months`, and so on from the `TODAY()` date.

I tried using the `IF` function but apparently, I'm not very good at DAX.

Thanks. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try using SWITCH function. For Example, `=SWITCH(DATEDIF(A1,TODAY(),"M"),0,"Its Today",3,"Within 3 Months")`

Comment: It's `DATEDIFF`, right? I uses `=SWITCH(DATEDIFF('Date'[Date],TODAY(),"M"),3,"3 Months", 6, "6 Months", 9 , "9 Months")` getting `The end of the input was reached.'

Comment: I have given you the Excel Formula as I don't have Power bi. I think in Power bi its DATEDIFF....
Don't forget to Vote for the Solutions That worked for you.

Comment: I'm getting the error `The end of Input was reached`. so it's not working for me

Comment: Try creating the formula with one value and increment in steps. Share the Formula you are using.

Comment: The formula worked but I'm not getting the desired output. I'm getting only 31 values not the desired 90 values. Formula:- `Column 4 = SWITCH(DATEDIFF('Date'[Date],TODAY(),MONTH), 3,"3 Months")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is abit tricky to solve your question, however if you understand the basic behind, you will find it easy to use, please take note that `Switch` is not able to use for calculation here due to `< or >' operator is not applicable:

Here is my dax formula to solve the month classification, accept the answer if helping :)

```
Month Class = 
var monthDiff = (YEAR(TODAY()) - YEAR(Sheet1[Date]))*12 + MONTH(TODAY()) - MONTH(Sheet1[Date])
return
IF(monthDiff < 4,"Last 3 Month",
    IF(monthDiff < 7, "Last 6 month", 
        IF(monthDiff <10,"Last 9 month",
            "more than a year")))
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Kin Siang. It's working now. Just one thing is it possible to subtract two dates?

Comment: Ya, definitely it is possible, you may open new thread if not able to get the expected output :)